# Table doesn't exist MySQL

Tags: mysql

In regards to [this guide for compiling Arcemu](http://arcemuwiki.blogspot.dk/2012/10/contents-how-to-compile-arcemu-with.html):

I have followed all steps and everything is fine until I reach the steps:

> At the command line, enter the following commands;
>
> ```
> create database arc_logon; 
> create database arc_characters; 
> create database arc_world;
> ```

This isn't the exact spot but shortly after the guide asks me to:

```
mysql -u root -p arc_logon
INSERT INTO `accounts` (login, password, gm, flags, banned) VALUES ('your-login-name', 'your-password', 'az', '24', '0');
```

This is right after the following step:

> ```
> ubuntu@ubuntu:/home/arcemu/src/code/sql$ ls -l
> total 480
> -rw-r--r-- 1 arcemu arcemu   2146 2011-05-12 22:03 2834_logon_structure.sql
> -rw-r--r-- 1 arcemu arcemu  36315 2011-05-12 22:03 3800_character_structure.sql
> -rw-r--r-- 1 arcemu arcemu 421549 2011-05-12 22:03 3955_world_structure.sql 
> drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 character_updates 
> drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 extra_scripts 
> drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 logon_updates 
> drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 misc 
> drwxr-xr-x 4 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 utilities 
> drwxr-xr-x 3 arcemu arcemu   4096 2011-05-12 22:03 world_updates
> ```

After executing the `INSERT INTO` line of code I receive the error:

```
Error 1146 (42502): Table 'arc_logon.accounts' doesn't exist
```

Why is there no accounts table populated when I created the database? Do I have to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open nautilus (file explorer) and navigate to:

`/home/arcemu/src/code/sql`

Make sure all these files exist there:
`logon_structure.sql`, 
`character_structure.sql`, 
`world_structure.sql`

Now, in your terminal, do:

`cd /home/arcemu/src/code/sql`

Then, import each of the above files, do:

`mysql -u root -p arc_logon < logon_structure.sql`

`mysql -u root -p arc_character < character_structure.sql`

`mysql -u root -p arc_world < world_structure.sql`

You will be asked to enter the mysql password after each one.

Comment: alright the files are tehre, but they are just named logon_structure.sql etc...without the numbers in front

Comment: Now i write : mysql -u root -p database_name < logon_structure.sql and it gives me an error 1064 saying i have an sql syntax in line 1

Comment: okay, nevermind it works after i hit enter password and stalls for a while....but are you sure i should use arc_logon as the database for all 3 and not arc_character or arc_world?

Comment: And if you haven't figured it out, type it how the files are named. if there are no numbers then don't enter the numbers in the command either.

Comment: i have been writing the files how they are named, still getting error 1064 in sql syntax....i've tried googling this...no solutions yet

Comment: @zibudo If you're getting an SQL sytax message it means that your import is working and SQL is paring them. However it means that the code in them is broken. There's nothingn you can do about that except for try to download it again. Or if you want to try and fix it yourself post the SQL code in another question.

Comment: I got the other two files: world and character sql files to work....but my logon structure sql file isnt working....looking into that right now

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

first open a connection to mysql

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

after successfully logging in

execute

```
USE arc_logon;
SHOW TABLES;
```

This will give you a list of all tables in arc_logon. If you can find the 'accounts' table then you should run the query and it will work

```
USE arc_logon;
INSERT INTO `accounts` (login, password, gm, flags, banned) VALUES ('your-login-name', 'your-password', 'az', '24', '0');
```

Or you can also do this

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'arc_logon' AND table_name= 'accounts'
```

If the above query return a single row, then the insert should work otherwise create the accounts table as it does not exists in this database.

Comment: yea i can do all of that, but i only get back an EMPTY SET. However, user Adelphia in the answers here says that I should have ran through a line of code which imports those tables...I think this is where the issue lies because I can't get that to work.